# What is the efficient way to check if some sub-array's are sorted or not when there are several queries?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Suppose an array `A = {5, 4, 3, 7, 9, 11, 2}`. There are `K` number of queries. In each query I will be given two integers `L` and `R` where `0 <= L <= R < N`(where N is the size of the Array). I have to tell if `A[L...R]` sub-array is sorted.

For example, 1st query asks me to tell if the sub-array from index 0 to 6 (0-based index) is sorted or not. The answer is, `A[0...6]` is not sorted. 
Then 2nd query asks me to tell if `A[2...5]` is sorted or not. This sub-array is sorted. Here is the way I approached it. Is there any better approach?

```
int main()
{
    int a[7] = { 5, 4, 3, 7, 9, 11, 2}, k = 2;

    for(int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        int l, r;
        cin >> l >> r;
        bool isSorted = true;
        for(int j = l; j < r; j++)
        {
            if(a[j] > a[j + 1] )
            {
                isSorted = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isSorted == true)
            cout << "Sorted" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Not Sorted" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I searched for answers but couldn't find anything that's why I asked here. Suppose an array {9, 1, 3, 5, 4, 2}. Now I have 2 queries. 1st query I have to tell if sub-array from index 1 to 6 is sorted(1-based index), which is not. Then in the 2nd query I have to tell if the sub-array from 2 to 4 index is sorted or not, which is sorted. If I try naive way It will take N * K time in the worst case (where N is array size and K is number of queries).  My question is, Is there any better approach?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code/attempt(s).

Comment: What if you just cache the intervals right after you check: both sorted and now. Anything that falls into a sorted interval is sorted. Intersected sorted intervals can be merged. Anything that contains unsorted interval as a whole - is unsorted. Unsorted intervals "unmerge" as soon as you explore more.

Comment: Why do you think this algorithm is not efficient?

Comment: @Gox: Perhaps because it is O(k*r) and there is an O(N) solution.

Comment: Because, size of the array is at most 10^5 and there will be at most 10^5 queries also.

Comment: @BenVoigt I did not say it is efficient, but rather wanted him to update a question to include his thoughts.

Comment: You could simplify your code by using [std::is_sorted()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted)

Comment: is_sorted() has time complexity of O(n)

Comment: @YaseenMollik it won't ever go below O(n) since it has to check every pair of consecutive elements.

Comment: You didn't read what I asked. There are K queries too. So it would take O(n*K) times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do a single pass through the data, storing at each index the closest preceding index at which the list decreased.

Then a query will consist of doing a lookup from the right index of the range, and comparing the resulting value to the left index of the range.

```
int main(void)
{
    constexpr int a[7] = { 5, 4, 3, 7, 9, 11, 2};
    constexpr size_t k = 2;
    constexpr size_t N = sizeof a/sizeof a[0];
    size_t b[N];

    { /* preprocess */
        size_t last_decrease = 0;
        b[0] = 0;
        for( int x = 1; x < N; ++x )
        {
            if (a[x] < a[x-1]) last_decrease = x;
            b[x] = last_decrease;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        int l, r;
        std::cin >> l >> r;
        bool isSorted = l >= b[r];

        if (isSorted)
            std::cout << "Sorted\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Not Sorted\n";
    }
}
```

No nested loops, therefore this solution has linear runtime.